# How to use $in operator with an array containing multiple or single value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im trying to create a mongoose query using the $in operator which specifically requires an array as the input.

I pass in an array of search.interests, however depending on the user input the interests array could be either 1 value or many. If it is many it works fine, if its a single value then the $in operator fails.

> "$in needs an array"

As i don't know how many interests my user will choose, how do i ensure search.interests is an array even with one value, so i can carry on using $in operator for both use cases.

```
search(req, res) {

    let search = req.query;

    console.log(search.interests);

    User.where('profile.interests').in(search.interests)
        .select('_id')
        .exec((err, users) => {

            if (err) {
                return res.json(err);
            }

            return res.json(users);

        });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force to array type : http://rextester.com/JFXO55055

```
interests_array = [].concat(search.interests || [])
```

in your code :

```
User.where('profile.interests').in([].concat(search.interests || []))
    .select('_id')
    .exec((err, users) => {

        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }

        return res.json(users);

    });
```